# Copy different worksheets from different workbooks vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a macro that will copy worksheets then save it as new.

But, I want to copy two worksheets then combine them into one, but the worksheets are located in two different workbooks.

for example:
workbook1 contains 2 worksheets (worksheet1, worksheet2)
workbook2 contains 3 worksheets (worksheet1, worksheet2, worksheet3)

I want to copy worksheet1 from workbook1 and worksheet1 from workbook2. then combine them since they both have the same table format.

I don't know how. I only know how to copy multiple worksheets from the same workbook. I also know how to combine them, my only problem how am I going to copy both worksheet1 from different workbook which is workbook1 and workbook2

I only have simple code for copying the data.
here's my code by the way:

```
saveFolder = "C:\Document\Macro"

path = "C:\Document\Workbook1"
fname = "Sample Account.xlsx"

Workbooks.Open path & fname
Sheets("Account1").Copy

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs saveFolder & "\Conso.xlsx", FileFormat:=51
Workbooks(fname).Close
```

the other file is located on folder **Workbook2** it filename is **Additional Accounts**

Comment: Welcome to Super User,, my simple suggestion is edit you post and include the VBA code you are using to Copy Sheets to New Workbook, will help us to modify it  to accomplish the job !!

Comment: @RajeshS alright :) I edited my question I added my code for copying the data :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This VBA (Macro) code will help you to Copy Worksheet of your choice from Source Workbook to combine into Active book.**

*This Code is interactive rather than Standard which makes the code versatile.*

```
Sub CombineSheets()
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim sFname As String
    Dim wBk As Workbook
    Dim wSht As Variant

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   sPath = InputBox("Enter File Path Of Source Workbook(s)")

   ChDir sPath

   sFname = InputBox("Enter the Filename")

   sFname = Dir(sPath & "\" & sFname & ".xl*", vbNormal)

   wSht = InputBox("Enter Worksheet Name To Copy")

   Do Until sFname = ""

       Set wBk = Workbooks.Open(sFname)
        Windows(sFname).Activate
        Sheets(wSht).Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        wBk.Close False
        sFname = Dir()
    Loop
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**How it works:**

- Copy & Paste this code as Standard Module with 
  the Master Workbook (in which you want to 
  combine Sheets).
- Run the Macro.
- First it asks for a path to the Source 
  Workbook(s).

**Note,** better Copy & Paste the File Path.

- Then ask the Workbook's Name, you may use 
  Wildcards also, or Workbook's name like 
  `Myworkbook`.
- Finally it ask for the Sheet Name to be copied.

Comment: wow thanks it worked well. I've changed some of the code to make it shorter. It worked perfectly Thank you :)

Comment: Glad to help you @gee,,, keep asking ☺